# GithubAPI Commit without fast-forward

Tags: git, github, github-api

since some days I try to interact with the GitHub API to create a commit.
My Problem is there the result in GIT, after the reference update to the new Commit.
Github returns every time with:

```
Status Code 422: {
    "message": "Update is not a fast forward",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/enterprise/2.22/rest/reference/git#update-a-reference"
}
```

But I don't want to create a fast forward commit just a new commit on the master branch. Which Param do I forgot or did I set something wrong?

To reproduce the error I used postman:

1. Create Blob - https://{{server}}/api/v3/repos/:owner/:repo/git/blobs

```
{
    "content":"This is my content at {{currentDate}}", 
    "encoding":"utf-8"

}
```

-> save response.sha in "shaBlob".
2. getRef - https://{{server}}/api/v3/repos/:owner/:repo/git/ref/heads/master
-> save response.object.sha in "shaMaster".
3. getLastCommit - https://{{server}}/api/v3/repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:commit_sha
-> save response.tree.sha in "shaMasterTree"
4. create Tree - https://{{server}}/api/v3/repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees
Body:

```
{
    "base_tree": "{{shaCommitLast}}",
    "tree": [{
        "path": "readme.md",
        "mode": "100644",
        "type": "blob",
        "sha": "{{shaBlob}}"
    }]
}
```

-> save response.sha in shaTreeNew
5. create Commit - https://{{server}}/api/v3/repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits
Body:

```
{
    "message": "This is a bot Commit",
    "tree": "{{shaTreeNew}}",
    "author": {
        "name": "ASLob",
        "email": "aslob@mydomain.com",
        "date": "{{currentDate}}"
    },
    "committer": {
        "name": "ASLob",
        "email": "aslob@mydomain.com",
        "date": "{{currentDate}}"
    }
}
```

-> save response.sha in shaCommitNew
6. update Reference - https://{{server}}/api/v3/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref
Body:

```
{
    "sha": "{{shaCommitNew}}",
    "force": false
}
```

Comment: "GitHub API to create a commit" --- why? Remember github is not git. Git is the version control software.

Comment: it is a bot which is running I a minimal container. It should create some default pages, if they are missing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to clone the repo, make the modifications, and then push the changes?

Comment: I don't have git in that pod where my bot is running. Some Git where my Bot is running contains many files and data. Not possible to clone all that code.

Comment: What about using a shallow clone?

Comment: I don't have git on my pod. Is there an mistake in my code, or is it not possible to do that via GitHub api?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the problem and found a solution.

When submitting a commit:

> parents: The SHAs of the commits that were the parents of this commit.
> If omitted or empty, the commit will be written as a root commit. For
> a single parent, an array of one SHA should be provided; for a merge
> commit, an array of more than one should be provided.
>
> In our case, for the parent, since we want to add another commit on a
> particular branch, we need to get the SHA of it.

You can get more information here: https://dev.to/bro3886/create-a-folder-and-push-multiple-files-under-a-single-commit-through-github-api-23kc